# Updating a Label

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, textbox, label, updates

What I need is that my label displays an addition between what is writed on 5 Textboxes.

I tried to do it when the textbox value is changed, but since there are 5 of them it takes a lot of repetitive code.

Is there a way to self- update the label? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register the same method on the TextChanged events of the textboxes :

```
public FooControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.TextChanged += textBoxes_TextChanged;
            textBox2.TextChanged += textBoxes_TextChanged;
            textBox3.TextChanged += textBoxes_TextChanged;
            textBox4.TextChanged += textBoxes_TextChanged;
            textBox5.TextChanged += textBoxes_TextChanged;
        }

        void textBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Content = ...
        }
```

or:

```
 var sumBoxes = new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textbox4, textbox5 };
           sumBoxes.ForEach(i => i.TextChanged += sumBoxes_TextChanged);
```

Comment: i want to keep a format on the label: Label.Text = Format(0, "$ #,##0.00") but when i make the addition the $ symbol disapear, how do i do to stop that from happening?